# Fancybox inserting DISPLAY NONE into image thumbnails

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I am using fancybox to display larger images of thumbnails. I have fancybox working on several of my pages, but on one page, fancybox is inserting "display: none" into the thumbnails....

Here is the page where none of the thumbnails show. If you look at the code, you will notice that the thumbnails have "display: none !important" ... which is why the page is unviewable. 
http://www.amazingdg.com/portfolio/advertising

However, plenty of other pages work completely fine. For example:
http://www.amazingdg.com/portfolio/packaging

Does anyone know why it works on every other page, but not on my "advertising" page?  Can anyone help me fix this? Thanks!

Comment: just a guess... are you not using an adblocker of some sort...? I use AdBlockerPlus in chrome, disabling it made me show your thumbs...

Comment: Well, that fixed it for that page. Unsure why it affects just the advertising page though, and not the other pages that use fancybox... (is it because the page is titled "advertising", and AdBlock sees it as a "threat")? Interesting (and extremely frustrating). Thanks for the help.

Comment: it probably is the cause, but you should ask AdBlock...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by webeno in the comments. AdBlock was causing the issue. Disabling it fixed the problem...